# How to Autofit the widgets in a view to variable window size automatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface, swt

I have an RCP application in which i changed position of the window(shell) and its size by overriding the postWindowCreate() method in ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class, the widgets in the views are not fitted to the changed window size, to see all widgets either i have to maximize the window or move scroll bars of the view to see all the widgets inside the view, is it possible to auto-fit(show all widgets in the current window size without moving scroll bars or maximizing the window) the widgets in the view even if the screen size varies.

Comment: After setting the size and position of your shell, are you doing a `shell.layout()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you change the size of the shell in `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen()`, not in `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowCreate()`:

```
public class ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor {
    @Override
    public void preWindowOpen() {
        final IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
        configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(800, 600));
        configurer.setShowCoolBar(false);
        configurer.setShowStatusLine(false);
        // configurer.setShellStyle(SWT.TITLE | SWT.RESIZE);
    }
}
```

Likewise, you can set the window title and the style of the window.

The position of the window is usually best set in `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowCreate()`...

If you must change the size of the window, then remember to call `shell.pack()`!